# ArcGIS Server - E-Tags

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, rest

From an ArcGIS Server (9.3.x or 10.x) instance, can anyone confirm if REST HTTP response headers are modified when the data within a layer is updated?

For example, if I query a layer at time `x` and get a `200 OK` response and E-Tag `y` and I query the same dataset at a later date, I'll generally receive a `304 Not Modified` response with the same E-Tag. However I'd expect the E-Tag to change and to receive a `200 OK` status if the layer data changed, is this the case?

If this is **not** the case, is there a way to test if data has changed since a particular date without actually pulling the data down.

Answer (score 1):

> If this is **not** the case, is there a way to test if data has changed since a particular date without actually pulling the data down.

Whether or not this is the case, if you're just speaking HTTP methods, then you should be able to use a HEAD request.

An HTTP HEAD request is the same as an HTTP GET request with the exception that the response does not include the data.

You could use cURL (https://curl.haxx.se/) to generate such a request like:

```
curl 
  --request HEAD "http://your.service/ows?service=WXS&request=...&"
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I'm specifically interested in ArcGIS server REST APIs. Yes, one would hope that they'd follow HTTP conventions, but I haven't been able to confirm if they do expire ETags (or provide some other way) to identify if a change has happened.

Comment: Some things to consider then, `can anyone confirm if REST HTTP response headers are modified when the data within a layer is updated`  There's no such thing as a REST HTTP response header, only an HTTP response header.  ETags are often disabled, so probably shouldn't be relied upon as a means of determining changes.